# Почему в Java на панели может не рисоваться прямоугольник?

Tags: java, графика, awt

Почему в Java на панели может не рисоваться прямоугольник?

```
public class FinanceMarketFrame extends JFrame {  
        private JPanel toolPanel;
        FinanceMarketFrame() {
        super("Графическое приложение");
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBounds(50,50,1000, 450);           
        toolPanel = new JPanel();
        toolPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, this.getContentPane().getHeight()));
        add(toolPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        toolPanel.getGraphics().setColor(Color.black);
        toolPanel.getGraphics().drawRect(5, 40, 5, 20);
        toolPanel.setOpaque(false);
        toolPanel.add(new JButton());
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Может.Судя по вашему коду у Вас происходит следующее (Если предварительно исправить пример т.к NullPointerException не даст двигаться дальше)Вы прорисовываете прямоугольник и за ним перерисовывается панель исключая все изменения описанные ранее.Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel toolPanel;

    Test() {
        super("Графическое приложение");
        setBounds(50, 50, 1000, 450);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        toolPanel = new JPanel();
        toolPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 90));
        add(toolPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        toolPanel.add(new JButton());

        setVisible(true);
        paint(getGraphics());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```